# Get DynamicResource Binding in WPF

Tags: wpf, binding, dynamicresource

Can any one help me to get DynamicResource Binding in WPF by code?

I have set binding Like follow,

TextBlock Background={DynamicResource ColorA} Name="TB" in Xaml.

and i need to get the - TB's background is binded to "ColorA". 
how can i access this DynamicResource Binding Expression in WPF by coding.
when i try to get TB.Background, it is white(#FFFFF..) or if i already given the value to the 
Resorce key "ColorA" that will be given.
but i want to get this Binding Expression.
Thank in advance for your Help.

---

I think my Question wasn't clear.
I want to get What Reource Binding was done to the "TB" in Xaml by code.
But the aren't any TB.GetResourceReference. I Want some think like that.
Where that Binding expression is kept in WPF. I need to get the TB's BackgroundProperty was 
Binded to Which( answer "ColorA") key?
thank a lot for sudden response.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the FrameworkElement.SetResourceReference method:

MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.setresourcereference.aspx

Provided your xaml has this:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="TB">
```

You can write this in the code behind:

```
TB.SetResourceReference(BackgroundProperty, "ColorA");
```

Comment: This is a great answer on how to create a DynamicResource binding in code. Not an answer to the OP's question, unfortunately, but well written & may help others who get here looking for this answer.  +1

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
YourControl.Style = this.FindResource(NameOfYourStyleForThisControl) as Style;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override ColorA inside it's parent by doing this

```
<TextBlock.Resources>
    <Background x:Key="ColorA">your color</Background >
<TextBlock.Resources>
```